# OR-01422 ORA-06512

Tags: plsql, oracle-12c

Can someone help to solve this error? I couldn't write pl/sql query of this .thanks.

```
spool 150OMGIddl.sql

    declare c clob;
    begin
   SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name,'150OMGI') into c from dba_tables u where owner='150OMGI';
   dbms_output.put_line(c);
   dbms_output.put(';');
  end;
/
spool off
```

error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

when I run `SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name,'150OMGI') from dba_tables u where owner='150OMGI';` I got 26 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script expects just 1 row. Not the 26 you get. You must use a cursor and loop through the rows that you get:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  CURSOR CRS IS
    SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name,'150OMGI')
    FROM   dba_tables u
    WHERE  owner='150OMGI';
  C CLOB;
BEGIN
  OPEN CRS;
  LOOP
    FETCH CRS INTO C;
    EXIT WHEN CRS%NOTFOUND;

    dbms_output.put_line(c);
    dbms_output.put(';');
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE CRS;
END;
/
```